# MySQL Query Optimization for large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query that take 50 seconds

```
SELECT `security_tasks`.`itemid` AS `itemid`
FROM `security_tasks`
INNER JOIN `relations` ON (`relations`.`user_id` = `security_tasks`.`user_id` AND    `relations`.`relation_type_id` = `security_tasks`.`relation_type_id` AND `relations`.`relation_with` = 3001 )
```

Records in security_tasks = 841321  ||  Records in relations = 234254

```
CREATE TABLE `security_tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Task_id` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `job_id` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `task_type_id` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `name` int(2) DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `itemid` (`itemid`),
  KEY `relation_type_id` (`relation_type_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1822995 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_with` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `relation_with` (`relation_with`),
  KEY `relation_type_id` (`relation_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1082882 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

what can i do to make it fast, like 1 or 2 seconds fast

EXPLAIN :

```
id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  relations   ref user_id,relation_with,relation_type_id  relation_with   5   const   169 Using where
1   SIMPLE  security_tasks  ref relation_type_id,user_id    user_id 5   transparent.relations.user_id   569 Using where
```

UPDATE :

adding a composite key minimized the time to 20 seconds

ALTER TABLE security_tasks ADD INDEX (user_id, relation_type_id) ; ALTER TABLE relations ADD INDEX (user_id, relation_type_id) ; ALTER TABLE relations ADD INDEX (relation_with) ;

The problem is when the relations table has large data for the selected user (relations`.`relation_with` = 3001 )

any ideas ?

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `EXPLAIN [your query]`

Comment: 1 SIMPLE relations ref user_id,relation_with,relation_type_id relation_with 5 const 169 Using where
1 SIMPLE security_tasks ref relation_type_id,user_id user_id 5 transparent.relations.user_id 569 Using where

Comment: ***UPDATE*** your question. Don't post the output in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your compound index slightly, don't do just two, but all three parts

ALTER TABLE relations ADD INDEX (user_id, relation_type_id, relation_with)

The index does not just have to be on the joined columns, but SHOULD be based on joined columns PLUS anything else that makes sense as querying criteria is concerned (within reason, takes time to learn more efficiencies).  So, in the case suggested, you know the join on the user and type, but are also specific to the relation with... so that is added to the same index.

Additionally, your security task table, you could add the itemID to the index to make it a covering index (ie: covers the join conditions AND the data element(s) you want to retrieve).  This too is a technique, and should NOT include all other elements in a query, but since this is a single column might make sense for your scenario.  So, look into "covering indexes", but in essence, a covering index qualifies the join, but since it also has this "itemid", the engine does not have to go back to the raw data pages of the entire security tasks table to get that one column.  It's part of the index so it grabs whatever qualified the join and comes along for the ride and you are done.

ALTER TABLE security_tasks ADD INDEX (user_id, relation_type_id, itemid) ;

And for readability purposes, especially with long table names, it's good to use aliases

```
SELECT 
      st.itemid
   FROM 
      security_tasks st
         INNER JOIN relations r
            ON st.user_id = r.user_id 
            AND st.relation_type_id = r.relation_type_id
            AND r.relation_with = 3001
```

Comment: @KareemSalama, did it resolve your performance issue of 20 sec?  If so, what is it down to now.

Comment: its 0.004. but unfortunately i have many fields to be selected in `security_tasks` table (i didn't put all fields here as its actually 85 fields).

I cannot index them all of course.

I am planning now to restructure my tables to avoid joining to the relation table :(